# Django context processor to check user permissions

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to write a context processor which will look the existing context, and if there is a form present, check that the user has permission to edit that object.  If not, I will overwrite that context variable.

How do I read the existing context from inside a context processor?

Edit:
The reason for using this type of context processor is to avoid having the check permissions with if statements in each view.  Some users will have read/write access, others will have read-only and others will have no access, at the object level.  I would like to manipulate the form accordingly after the view has been processed.

Comment: Please define *has permission to edit that object*

Comment: Permissions will be handled by an object-level permission package.  Most likely django-rulez.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just wrap the view with a `user_passes_test` decorator? You can run any checks you like there -- no hacks required.

Comment: user_passes_test won't do quite what I want, since some users may have read-only access.  Maybe I can write a decorator that can make the form read-only in some cases.  I'll need to read up on decorators.

Comment: Please, do read up on decorators. It is less a hack to iterate over all urls and decorate all views than to monkey patch (that's what i was thinking when i talked about "less hacky"). But the most convincing is that i can guarantee instant gratification for learning to make decorators. You'll give your code an elegance which you have not experienced until you can do decorators.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I am going to handle some of my basic views using the method described [here](http://blog.vmfarms.com/2010/01/helpful-django-view-decorator-pattern.html).  That seems like a very DRY option.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [django-authority](http://packages.python.org/django-authority/), or [any authority package](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/authorization/). Although, I cannot guarantee that they don't rely on hacks themselves, but at least you wouldn't be alone using the hacks. That said, here is a working solution to your issue:

1. **Monkey patch django.template.base.RequestContext**, to set request.context = self.
2. **Create a template context processor**, which can use request.context
3. **Add the context processor to settings**, and you're good to go

Here is an example, which you can just paste in settings.py, it works:

```
def print_context(request):
    print request.context.get('form', 'No form in this context')
    return {}

from django.template.base import RequestContext
orig_init = RequestContext.__init__
def new_init(self, request, **kwargs):                                           
    request.context = self
    orig_init(self, request, **kwargs)                                           
RequestContext.__init__ = new_init

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',                                       
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',                                       
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'settings.print_context',
)
```

**Note that you are working against Django's design**, I posted this answer assuming you know what you're doing - you know both Python and Django very well.

Comment: I had disregarded django-authority since it didn't seem active on bitbucket, but I'll give it another look.  I agree I would rather not be alone using hacks like the one you mention.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  You convinced me that context processors aren't the best way to handle this.